# RewriteCond to skip rules if the file exists doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I'm using this in my conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$      /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

But files such as `/theme/styles.css` still get redirected to index.php

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: Is this in an `.htaccess`, or in the apache conf? If in an `.htaccess`, have you correctly set the `RewriteBase`?

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, /theme/styles.css is a REQUEST_URI not a REQUEST_FILENAME; the _FILENAME is a full path on disk. Try adding debugging to see what is being evaluated:

```
RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Find the relevant section of your request in the log and it *should* show you what's wrong, but if not then paste it for us to see.